# Trouble Populating Custom Rows in Bootstrap Table .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what is going on. I have a project that dynamically builds a table based on how many "Groups" the user has. Each "GroupTable" is hidden or shown via horizontal tabs. The "GroupTable" has entries or rows. The rows contain Text and Buttons that interact with the rest of the program (ex: Edit Entry Button next to Entry Title)

I build these entries and rows using an Ajax call, through my C# code, DB, and outputs to a List of objects. The rows are build in JavaScript manually appending the text var to the corresponding "GroupTable":

```
function PopulateListings(data) {


    $(data).each(function (index, obj) {
var tr = "<tr>" +

            "<td>" +
                obj.Title +
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' id='btnEditList" + obj.listID + "' onclick='editListing(" + obj.listID + ")'><span class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' ></span></button>"+
            "</td >" +

            "<td>" + obj.Username1 + "</td>" +
            "<td valign='middle'>" +
                "<div id='pwtext_" + obj.listID + "'><label valign='middle' style='padding-right: 10px'>********</label>" + 
                //"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick='viewPassword(" + obj.listID + ")'><span class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>" +
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick='copyPassword(" + obj.listID + ")'>Copy Password</button>" +
                "</div > " +

            "</td>" +

            "<td>" + obj.URL + "</td>" +

            "<td>" + obj.Username2 + "</td>" +

            "<td>" + obj.Notes_Short + "</td>" +

            "</tr>";
        var appendto = "#tablegroup_" + obj.groupID;
        $(appendto).append(tr);
 });

}
```

This will build a row for each listing that is passed through. The "GroupTables" are set up like so:

```
var tableheader2 = "<div id='" + obj.groupID + "'class='tabcontent' style='display: " + blockstyle + ";' > " +
            "<table data-toggle='table'  data-url='data1.json'  data-pagination='true' data-search='true' id='tableid" + obj.groupID + "' > " +
                "<thead>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<th data-sortable='true'>Name/Title</th>" +
                        "<th>Username</th>" +
                        "<th>Password</th>" +
                        "<th>URL</th>" +
                        "<th>Username2</th>" +
                        "<th>Notes</th>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
            "<tbody id='tablegroup_" + obj.groupID + "' > </tbody> </table > </div > </div > ";


        $('#tablecontainer').append(tableheader2);
```

So everything is fine and dandy but now I want to implement a Bootstrap Table (BT) to be able to at least sort the data. Now what happens is the data is not loaded into the table using this function. I want to be able to stick my previous codes data to the corresponding tableID and then call bootstrapTable() to add that functionality.

```
$(data).each(function (index, obj) {
                var table_id = "#tableid" + obj;
                $(table_id).bootstrapTable();
            });
```

Order of operations of the code as follows:
1.) Load Page
2.) Load Groups
3.) Populate Group Tabs and Empty Tables
4.) Load Entries into the Empty Tables
5.) Convert normal table to bootstrapTable()

Am I messing up the order of operations? Should I be appending the entry data to a different element so it does not go away? right now the table outputs "No matching records found"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I figured out a decent solution that didn't require much code refactoring.

Part of my issues was the fact I had to manually set the Group

```html
var table_id = "#tableid" + obj.groupID;
        $(table_id).bootstrapTable({
            search: true,
            sortable: true,
            pagination: false,
            columns: [{
                    field: 'Title',
                    title: 'Name/Title',
                    sortable: true,

                },
                {
                    field: 'Username1',
                    title: 'Main Username',
                    sortable: true
                },
                {
                    field: 'passwordPlain',
                    title: 'Password'
                },
                {
                    field: 'URL',
                    title:'URL'
                },
                {
                    field: 'Username2',
                    title: 'Email/Username2',
                    sortable: true
                },
                {
                    field: 'Notes_Short',
                    title: 'notes'
                }
                

            ]

        });
```

After word I was able to populate the rows by appending them, and include a HTML object

```html
function PopulateListings2(data) {
    $(data).each(function (index, obj) {
        var arr = [
            {
                'Title': obj.Title + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' id='btnEditList" + obj.listID + "' onclick='editListing(" + obj.listID + ")'><span class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' ></span></button>",
                'Username1': obj.Username1,
                'passwordPlain': "********",
                'URL': obj.URL,
                'Username2': obj.Username2,
                'Notes_Short': obj.Notes_Short

            }
        ];
        var $table = $('#tableid' + obj.groupID)
        $table.bootstrapTable('append', arr);
    });
    
}
```